# iOS 7 XCode 5 Storyboard set orientation to Landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have set the allowed orientation on the project settings to Landscape only.
Now I want to design on the storyboard, but the storyboard is portrait, I only support Landscape so I try to make the storyboard orient on landscape, I go to Simulated Metrics, and I didn't see anything that says "orientation", just ViewController stuff, like Layout, Extend Edges, Transition Style, etc...

I am making a game with SpriteKid and I'm trying to make a Main Menu with the storyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it might be collapsed. You need to hover your mouse over the title to see the `show` button which will expand the list.

[image]

The full options list will be shown as this image :

[image]

Comment: Why would they do that, there isn't much on the pane. Why would they hide it by default. That's just crazy. Anyways, I found it. Thanks.

Comment: This way you have to change  orientation for all the controllers on storyboard one by one. What about to set the default orientation for all on storyboard ?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to tap close enough to the border of view. The menu is visible when the border change into blue one

Answer (score 0):

It's there. Second row.
Don't know why you can't see it.

[image: Orientation - Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

Choose main.storyboard -> choose Viewcontroller (1) -> choose button "show" (2) -> change Orientation: "Landscape" (3)

Comment: If you will add a sample code along with your answer it will  more helpful