# Cannot fix the viewcontroller to landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I try to fix my viewcontroller to landscape using Simulated Metrics by changing the orientation to Landscape (like [change orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495340/ios-7-xcode-5-storyboard-set-orientation-to-landscape). It worked a few days ago. But when I created a new project (a single application), and repeat these steps, it does not work anymore.

Is there any solution for that? Or I missed something?

Note: I am using XCode5 and iOS 7.

Comment: you have to provide code to ask what was wrong with your approach to prevent being downvoted.

Comment: The thing I missed is not set up the Deployment Info of the project. If I set the Device Orientation of the Deployment Info to Landscape Left, the problem will be resolved. Could you please close this topic for me? Thanks

Comment: don't have enough rep to do so. Your suggestion is an answer though. Answer it yourself. That will 'close' it

Answer (score 0):

Set the Device Orientation of the Deployment Info to Landscape Left, the problem will be resolved.